# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, custom-field, functions

I have this code from home.php that will going to display a content from a page which has a custom post type of "about"

```
<?php   
    $post_status1  = 'publish'; 
    $post_type1 = 'page';
    $featucat = "about";
    $featucount = "1";

    $my_query = new WP_Query('post_status='. $post_status1 .'&post_type='. $post_type1.'');  
    if ($my_query->have_posts()){
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

            $front_values = get_post_custom_values('Homepage_Blog_01p', get_the_ID());
            foreach ( $front_values as $front_key => $result_value ) {
                if($result_value == 'about') {
?>

                    <div class="thewidgets">
                        <?php
                        $description_values = get_post_custom_values('Description_Field', get_the_ID());
                        foreach ( $description_values as $description_key => $description_value ) {
                            echo $description_value;

                        }
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Read the whole post" class="rm">Read More</a>
                    </div>
    <?php } } endwhile; } ?>
```

but unfortunately, I got this error

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\PROGRAM FILES\wamp\www\westchester\wp-content\themes\computerrepair\footer.php on line 22"
```

does anyone here could atleast point me where i get wrong? I tried organizing the brackets "{}" and also checking line 22 as the error pointed but I had no idea how to apply solutions.

PS: let me know if you want to see the codes from functions.php that is relevant from the codes above.

Comment: Homepage_Blog_01p & Description_Field - what do u mean by these fields.

Comment: THIS QUESTION has ALREADY BEEN ANSWERED [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303142/warning-invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach-php-wordpress)

Comment: @JMau: not been answered yet, instead act like a duplicate post but not similar concept of post through here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ for more accurate answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$front_values` does not contain an array. The [`get_post_custom_values()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_values) function does not always return an array. In this case, use this to force an array:

```
$front_values = (array) get_post_custom_values( 'Homepage_Blog_01p', get_the_ID() );
```

Comment: figure it out now, thank you for the guide! works like charm ;)